# Bergmann's rule and Allen's rule: endotherms and ectotherms

Tags: ecology, temperature, adaptation

Surface area to volume ratio (in terms of heat conservation) is not the only mechanism, but it is still an important mechanism for explaining Bergmann's rule and Allen's rule. Given that, I want to know why these rules are primarily applied to endotherms. I know there are some ectotherms that follow the rules, but here I am not asking for examples.

Comment: I guess, it is because these rules refer to how animal bodies are evolved to minimize heat loss, which is relevant only for endotherms (who have a different internal homeostatic temperature) and not for ectotherms, whose body temperature is equilibriated with that of the environment, making heat saving mechanisms redundant.